# Running rake db:seed isn't loading from seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to seed a set of football teams and football positions, and rails is strangely simply not doing it.

```
rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

All looks fine but when I bring up my site, (which was working peachy before, I know it's not the code there) there are no records.

I'm loading three objects: teams, players, and positions. Interestingly, when I got to make a new team, there are no fields, but when I go to make a new player, there ARE fields.

**Seeds.rb looks like this:**

```
position = Position.create(:positionName => 'Quarterback', :positionShort => 'QB', :stance => 'offense')
team = Team.create( name:'Patriots', location:'New England', conference:'AFC', division:'East', wins:'5', losses:'3')
```

Let me know what else you'll need to see, I am at a crossroads of inexperience and an inexplicable error.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'm going to make a suggestion with the hope that you'll see an error. In your seeds file use `create!` instead of `create`. That will cause the operation to throw an exception if the model doesn't meet the constraints. Give that a shot and see if it helps.

```
position = Position.create!(:positionName => 'Quarterback', :positionShort => 'QB', :stance => 'offense')
team = Team.create!( name:'Patriots', location:'New England', conference:'AFC', division:'East', wins:'5', losses:'3')
```

Comment: Good call Dan, and Ben (sung like the Jackson Five), lose the Snake Case. gross :-) `:position_short` and `:position_name` etc... Five bucks it's attr_accessible

Comment: Much appreciated! That did the trick. I had a ton of validation problems, it stepped through them all, and that did it. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Would +10 if i can

Comment: that was a great solution bro. really helpful. thanks a lot.

Comment: Comes in handy when the model is throwing an exception and not even trying to execute the SQL.  Excellent catch.  `create!` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative solution?

Hey everyone, just wanted to add a possible solution in case the following suggestions above don't work.

I had to reset my database or else rails 'db:seed' would fail the same way as mentioned above.

This worked for me:

```
rails db:migrate:reset
rails db:seed
```

Comment: or just `rails db:setup`

Answer (score 0):

Re: Alternative solution?

Careful - running 'rails db:migrate:reset' will truncate all tables in the database, destroying any data that might be there.  This command is intended when setting up a new database from seeds where initial attempts might have left incorrect or inconsistent data in the database.

From the Rails docs:

> 4.3 Resetting the Database
> The bin/rails db:reset command will drop the database and set it up again. This is functionally equivalent to bin/rails db:drop db:setup.